# Solving a sequential problem with Scala apache spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parallel-processing

On Scala Spark, given a sorted dataset of S and B, select pairs of S and B with minimum ranking, ensuring unique values for each S and each B.

Sample input:

```
|Rank|S  |B  |
|----|---|---|
|   1|S1 |B1 |
|   2|S2 |B1 |
|   3|S3 |B1 |
|   4|S1 |B2 |
|   5|S3 |B1 |
|   6|S2 |B2 |
```

Sample Output:

```
|Rank|S  |B  |
|----|---|---|
|   1|S1 |B1 |
|   6|S2 |B2 |
```

I understand how this can be solved sequentially, however, is it possible to solve it using Spark? If so, how?

Comment: Why '2 S1 B2' is not present in the output? Isn't 2 the minimum rank for that pair?

Comment: @LizardKing because S1 can only appear once, and the combination S1 B1 has a lower rating.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial solution, but I think that if your partitions are made right, you could use `mapPartitions` to do the job per partition. Something like the following:

```scala
val rdd: RDD[(Int, String, String)] = ...
rdd.mapPartitions { it =>
  it.foldLeft(List.empty[(Int, String, String)]) {
    case (Nil, e) => List(e)
    case ((i, ci1, ci2) :: tail, (j, cj1, cj2)) =>
      if (ci1 == cj1 || ci2 == cj2)
        (i, ci1, ci2) :: tail
      else
        (j, cj1, cj2) :: (i, ci1, ci2) :: tail
  }
}
```